# valores en una instancia de la clase (iniciación directa)

Tags: c++

tengo una clase la cual contiene una variable privada de tipo `int` y en la que en el constructor le asigno en valor cero de esta forma

```
class clase {
    unsigned int mivariable;
public:
    clase();
    int funcionQueRetornaVariable();
} 


clase::clase():mivariable(0) {
}

int clase::funcionQueRetornaVariable() 
{
    return this->mivariable;
}

clase obj:
cout << obj.funcionQueRetornaVariable(); // me muestra basura =(
```

pero cada vez que creo una instancia de mi variable esta no contiene en memoria el valor cero si no que guarda basura a diferencia de cuando utilizo

```
class clase {
    unsigned int mivariable = 0;
    clase();
}
clase::clase {
}
```

la cual cada vez que creo una objeto si le guarda el valor cero.
por que pasa esto?

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir algo más de código? El ejemplo que has puesto es más bien escaso.

Comment: si señor, enseguida modifico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes asignar el valor 0 a una variable de instancia de dos maneras:

1. En el constructor:

   ```
   class clase
   {
       unsigned int mivariable;
   public:
       clase() : mivariable(0) {};
   };
   ```
2. A partir de C++11 y en adelante, en la propia declaración:

   ```
   class clase
   {
       unsigned int mivariable = 0;
   public:
   };
   ```

Ambas opciones son mutuamente compatibles, por lo que puedes tener inicialización en el constructor e inicialización en la declaración:

```
class clase
{
    unsigned int mivariable = 0;
public:
    clase() : mivariable(0) {};
    clase(unsinged int valor) : mivariable(valor) {};
};
```

También puedes separar la definición de la declaración, como haces en tus ejemplos:

```
class clase
{
    unsigned int mivariable = 0;
public:
    clase();
    clase(unsinged int valor);
};

clase::clase() : mivariable(0) {} // fijate que es clase::clase, no clase::constructor
clase::clase(unsinged int valor) : mivariable(valor) {}
```

#### Problema.

> Cada vez que creo una instancia de mi variable esta no contiene en memoria el valor cero si no que guarda basura.

C++ tiene normas estrictas sobre la inicialización de datos, sigue la filosofía de "*No pagues por lo que no usas*"; que aplicado a este caso, significa que no se les da valor a las variables a no ser que se lo pidas.

Suponiendo que la clase `clase` fuese así:

```
class clase
{
public:
    unsigned int mivariable;
};
```

Dependiendo de cómo creases la instancia de `clase` la variable `clase::mivariable` sería inicializada a valor por defecto (`0`) o no sería inicializada (así que contendría *basura*); por ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
    clase c;
    clase d{};

    std::cout << c.mivariable << '\n'
              << d.mivariable << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

En el caso de `c.mivariable` se mostrará *basura* porque hemos instanciado `clase` con [inicialización por defecto](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization). Este tipo de inicialización no realiza ninguna operación que no esté programada: "*No paga por lo que no usa*".

En el caso de `d.mivariable` se mostrará `0` porque hemos instanciado `clase` con [inicialización por valor](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). Este tipo de inicialización aplica (si es posible) la inicialización por valor a los sub-componentes del objeto, en el caso de `mivariable` la inicializa a 0.

Comment: muchas gracias muy bien explicado

Comment: Sin saber la implementación de la función `funcionQueRetornaVariable` no se si te he resuelto el problema.

Comment: modifico otra vez para agregar la función